# Django: Pass URL parameter to context_data in generic.CreateView

Tags: python, django

I have created two url paths.

```
path('addhours/<int:jobNr>/', views.AddHoursView.as_view(), name='addhours'),
path('addhours/', views.AddHoursView.as_view(), name='addhours'),
```

And a `CreateView` for these paths.

```
class AddHoursView(generic.CreateView):

    template_name = "worktime/addhours.html"
    form_class = AddHoursForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('worktime:myjobs')

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        # pass "jobNr" keyword argument from the current url to form
        kwargs = super(AddHoursView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['jobNr'] = self.kwargs.pop(JOB_PARAM, None)
        return kwargs
```

And a form, where the number of fields depends on if the parameter exists in the URL.

```
class AddHoursForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):   
        #Add jobworker field to from Worktime model if any jobNr pass in url
        #When in url will be parameter. Job foreignkey will be set by automat.
        self.jobNr = kwargs.pop('jobNr', None)
        super(AddHoursForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.jobNr:
            self.fields['jobWorker'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Job.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = WorkTime
        fields = ['date', 'hours', 'description']

        widgets = {
            'date': forms.SelectDateWidget(empty_label=("Choose Year", 
                                                        "Choose Month", 
                                                        "Choose Day"))
        }
```

Now I want to have in `AddHoursView` `context["jobNr"] = "bar"` where the URL is `/url/bar`

In `AddHoursView`'s `def context_data(self, **kwargs)` I tried:

- `self.request.GET` gives me empty QueryDict
- `self.kwargs['jobNr']` give me a key error

I need access to the url parameter if it exist, to pass this jobNr to template, so override `form_valid` is not what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you are popping the value from `self.kwargs`, which removes it. That means it is no longer there when you try to access it in `get_context_data`. Since the argument is optional, you can use `get()` instead.

Change the method to:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(AddHoursView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['jobNr'] = self.kwargs.get('JOB_PARAM')
    return kwargs
```

Then in `get_context_data` you can do:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    kwargs = super(AddHoursView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    kwargs['jobNr'] = self.kwargs.get('JOB_PARAM')
    return kwargs
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I was thinking all the time about my django fail and dat was just simply python ofc My fail ;P